# Same seed, PL/R vs. R, different results (Random Forest)

Tags: r, postgresql, random, navicat, plr

I have an R function that takes some input data that contains missing values, uses Random Forest imputation to impute those values (through the rfImpute function from RandomForest package) and then goes through a RF importance calculation to identify the relative importance of variables (through ranger from the ranger package). The function has the seed 2018.

When I run the function using R with set.seed(2018), I get a set of results. When running the exact same function, the exact same input data and using the exact same seed in PL/R (using Navicat) the results are different.

I am having a really hard time understanding what could be causing this issue as everything is the exact same between the two (except one is R and the other is PL/R). For some input datasets, the results are equivalent but for others they are not. What could the problem be?

Note: I am not able to provide a simple example since my data is confidential.

Comment: do the results within R and PL/R stay the same with each run? We had some changing RF-results with each run despite having set the same seed in each run. It turned out, that the order of the Input-Data (which came from an external source) varied. The split in train and test data was based on a random selection of indices from 1 to NROW(data)... So maybe you are having something similar like this?

Comment: @TinglTanglBob the results they the same with each run... I am ordering the data once it gets inputted so I don't think that's the problem?

Comment: Do you get the same random numbers when you call `set.seed(2018); runif(10)` within PL/R and local R?

Comment: When retrieving the data set, is the order of the records fixed (and the same)

Comment: @RalfStubner yep, I get the same numbers... so confused by this

Comment: @joop I am ordering the data inside the R Script, so not sure how that could be the cause?

Comment: In that case you will have to provide a minimal example. Instead of your confidential data you can produce a similar random dataset.